# Include html file in html file

Tags: html, include

I haven't been able to find an answer on this.

I want to have a file called `header.html`, where my html code for my header is writen.

Then on all my pages, I want to load that header onto the page. This is so I only have to change it at one place in the code when needed, and get cleaner code.

I would like to *not* use php or any server-based language, but if that is the only option, please let me know :)

Comment: Have you considered using the [template tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_template.asp) or [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)?

Comment: Use an html Iframe, or php include.